# How to clear history from "Run Command" / Alt + F2 on gnome

Tags: gnome

How to remove the history from the `Run a command` window that opens up on <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> on CentOS 6 and above?

Comment: Doesn't look like gnome3 on CentOS 6

Comment: @don_crissti, thanks for the pointer. Found the was to reset the list on gnome-2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a terminal and run:

```
dconf reset /org/gnome/shell/command-history
```

or

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell command-history
```

For gnome2:

```
gconftool-2 -s -t string /apps/gnome-settings/gnome-panel/history-gnome-run []
```

Comment: Both the commands says "command not found"

Answer (score 0):

I'm still using RHEL 6, so I modify the below file

```
~/.gconf/apps/gnome-settings/gnome-panel/%gconf.xml
```

How do I found it?
for all XML files under home, grep the string you normally use under alt-f2